# jQuery Validate plugin with multiple select boxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validate to validate my form. The problem is that I have a form with multiple select boxes (dynamic number) and it has a dynamic name -> `answers[$question['id']]`

I've seen some scripts when there's a fixed name you can use that to address all the input fields like so.

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        "answers[]" = "required"
    }
});
```

But in my example this is not possible, Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You have a syntax error.  it's `field: rule`, not `field = rule`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly,

it's not `"answers[]" = "required"`

it's `"answers[]": "required"`

Notice the colon in place of your equals sign.

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        "answers[]": "required"
    }
});
```

Secondly, that would only assign the `required` rule to a single field with `name="answers[]"`.

If you want to easily assign this rule to multiple fields with `name="answers[1]"`, `name="answers[2]"`, `name="answers[3]"`, etc., then you'll need to do one of two things...

1)  Declare the `required` rule inline...

using `class`:

```
<input type="text" name="answers[1]" class="required" />
<input type="text" name="answers[2]" class="required" />
<input type="text" name="answers[3]" class="required" />
```

OR with HTML5:

```
<input type="text" name="answers[1]" required="required">
<input type="text" name="answers[2]" required="required">
<input type="text" name="answers[3]" required="required">
```

And jQuery:

```
$('#form').validate(); // initialize the plugin
```

**DEMO #1**:  http://jsfiddle.net/7JHWf/

---

2)  Or assign the rule dynamically using the `rules()` method to all fields with a `name` starting with `answers`:

```
$('#form').validate(); // initialize the plugin

// assign the rules
$('input[name^="answers"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
});
```

**DEMO #2**:  http://jsfiddle.net/7JHWf/1/

Comment: what a great answer. Just what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can just select the select boxes you're interested in by grabbing all select boxes or adding a specific class to them, then using each() to loop through:

```
$('select') or $('select.specificClass').each(function() {}
```

You don't need to know the name / id of each box to be able to select and loop through it. You can reference the current item value within the each() loop using:

```
$(this).val()
```