# How to use jqueryvalidation containing fields with HTML field names as PHP arrays?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-validate

I am using [jqueryvalidation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) library for validation of my forms. It works perfectly other than the input fields that have the following structure:

```
<input name="my_name[]">    
<input name="my_name[]">
  .
  .
  .
<input name="my_name[]">
```

The number of these `<input>` are not known in advance.

Now my question is that how to add `rules` for these elements, as `[]` are not valid identifier characters? Does JavaScript has something like PHP escaping mechanism: `{'my_name[]'}`?

Note: Usage of `rules` object in jqueryvalidation found [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate):

```
$(".selector").validate({
    rules: {
        // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
        name: "required",
        // compound rule
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26029429/594235

Comment: and this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19011151/594235